# How can button save go direct link

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I make the vacations form from lists like this image
Ok
[image]
Input all data and save give this image i don't like it 
[image]
I wanna go to another page it have massage done.. Wait approve from your boss i dont like the user view all data as image number two so how can make a direct link to another page after click on save button

Comment: your question is confusing can you re-frame it so that all can understand it?

Comment: This is a good or you need more clarification

Comment: Do you want the workflow to display approved from your manager?

Comment: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.nl/2009/06/sharepoint-redirecting-to-page-after.html

Answer (score 2):

Your new item page probably has a link like this: /NewForm.aspx?Source=...

Replace the link after ?Source= with the page you want to go to

Comment: You are not understand me